# In how many ways can $48$ bottles be distributed so that each surveyors get at least $2$ bottles of one particular type and at least $3$ of the other

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

> Two cases of soft drinks , $24$ bottles of one type and $24$ of another , are distributed among $5$ surveyors who are conducting taste test.In how many ways can $48$ bottles be distributed so that  each surveyors get at least $2$ bottles of one particular type and at least $3$ of the other ?

The given answer is $$C(18,14)\times C(13,9)$$

I see the result by generating functions and inclusion-exclusion .My question is that why the answer is not equal to  $$2 \times C(18,14)\times C(13,9)$$

Because we do not know which type of drink has at least $2$ bottles or at least $3$ bottles .

I think that we should have thought this seperation.Why the answer is $C(18,14)\times C(13,9)$ instead of $2 \times C(18,14)\times C(13,9)$ ?

Answer (score 1):

The key lies in the wording "... at least 2 bottles of one **particular** type and at least 3 of the other."

Also, even if the word **"particular"** was removed from the phrase, you couldn't multiply by 2 because there would be symmetrical final configurations that satisfied both the 2−3 and 3−2 conditions.

Comment: +1) The same question but with absence of the word "particular" might be interesting.

Comment: your last claim does not make sense to me. Assume that there are two drinks such as A and B. We can disperse them like $2A-2A-2A-2A-16A$ and $3B-3B-3B-3B-12B$ to $5$ surveyors ,respectively.However , dispersing like $2B-2B-2B-2B-16B$ and $3A-3A-3A-3A-12A$ is different. When we give the property having at least $3$ bottle to dirink $B$ ,its distribution become different when we give the property having at least $2$ bottle

Comment: What about symmetrical final configurations, eg $(3,3), (3,3), (3,3), (3,3), (12,12) and the like ?